# Can't open page in browser from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I checked out a project from TFS I had worked on a while ago, but when I pressed ctrl+F5 to launch it from Visual Studio, I got this message:

> This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your protection.

How do I open this page?

Comment: Perhaps you should google the error message.

Comment: If you take the URL and paste it in to Chrome/IE/Opera/etc... does it give you the same error

Comment: robbie is correct below http://bdbits.wordpress.com/2008/07/01/unblock-a-nonstandard-port-in-firefox3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project and select Properties. Select the "web" tab and select "Auto assign Port" under Servers. Visual studio will automatically assign a port when it runs for you.

[image]

Or if you know a port which is available to use, you can specify that in the  "specific port" section.

Comment: This would surely make the problem worse as you would have no way of setting the allowed ports in firefox....

Answer (score 3):

It is because the dynamic port of the visual studio is blocked by Firefox. See the solution here

[Solution](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0KvzmINohdUJ%3awww.securitypronews.com/news/securitynews/spn-45-20061016SolutiontotheFirefoxportproblem.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)

**Taken from the above link**

The built in webserver in Visual Studio 2005, formerly known as Casini, uses a dynamic or static port on the localhost machine (e.g. http://localhost:2049/default.aspx).

It is dynamic by default, but you can make it static if you choose. That works very well except when you try it in Firefox. It simply gives you this response:

This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has cancelled the request for your protection.

It does that by default whenever you use a port other than port 80 - the default website port. It took me a lot of digging to find the solution and here it is.
- Open Firefox

- Type about:config in the address field
- Right click anywhere on the screen
- Click new > string
- Enter preference name as: network.security.ports.banned.override
- Enter string value as: 2049 (or whatever port number you want)

Comment: one day that link may be dead, you could have posted the solution here and included the link as reference to show where you got the solution

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Type `about:config` in the firefox address bar.
2. Search for `network.security.ports.banned.override` (if this doesn't exist... right click and create it - [new]->[string])
3. Set the port number to a number you want to use with cassini. You can also use a range of ports (eg 8080-8090)

Once you have done this, you can then set the port to be used in visual studio as Shyju has suggested but instead of setting it to `auto-assign port` set it to the port you have configured in step 3 above.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port? (right click the project and properties (or alt + enter) and Specify port